# playing sound when the button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to make a simple code that if the user clicked the button the sound is played.

here is the code:

```
<script>
function play(){
$("body").append("<embed src='play.mp3' autostart='true' loop='false' width='2'    height='0'></embed>");
}
</script>

<form action="" method="post">
<input type="button" onclick="play()" value="click">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function playIt()
{
   document.getElementById("embed").innerHTML="<embed src='play.mp3' autostart=true loop=false volume=100 hidden=true>";
   return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <button type="button" onclick="playIt()">play</button>
        <div id="embed"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```